# Grid view alignment issue

Tags: android

Hi below the images showing my query please help me any one.

This is my requirement:
[image]

I am using grid view. But now I am getting like this.
[image]

Comment: Try aligning grid view items to center?

Comment: Fill the first column in last row with an invisible view the same size of the others.

Answer (score 0):

Try center_vertical in the layout for it children.and centerInParent if available and gravity="center".

Comment: Shouldn't it be center_horizontal?

Comment: it should vertically aligned relative to its  siblings.Though both should be applicable in this case.

Comment: <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.37">
            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/alphabets_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:numColumns="4"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp">
            </GridView>
        </RelativeLayout>

Comment: above i mentioned my xml

Comment: did you try adding the above attributes?

Comment: android:gravity="center_horizontal" or centerInParent="true" even this sometimes work android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

Comment: <GridView
                android:id="@+id/alphabets_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:numColumns="4"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp"> // but not working

Comment: still no prevail? for the parent layout use the gravity="center"

Comment: Why not just use RelativeLayout?

Comment: why you mean@Roger Belk?